# How to create shortcut for a command in terminal?

Tags: shortcuts, command-line

I want to create a shortcut for a command in terminal. Like for a command
 "ssh user@123.45.7.123",
I just want a command "user" and the above command will run.
Is this possible, and if so how can it be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 69):

The shortcuts for commands are known as aliases.
The syntax to create an alias is:

```
alias custom_command='original_command'
```

**Example:**
For creating an alias for update and upgrade we should type the following in terminal,

```
alias update='sudo apt-get update'    

alias upgrade='sudo apt-get upgrade'
```

So to create an alias for your command open the termianl and type:

```
alias user='ssh user@123.45.7.123'
```

Comment: If you want to have this command available in every terminal, you need to add this line to `~/.bash_aliases`. Then it will be automatically loaded.

Comment: i dont have any ~/.bash_aliases file should i create it?

Comment: That depends on your `~/.bashrc` . Does it source `~/.bash_aliases` ? If yes, then just create it.

Comment: @rohit the `.bash_aliases` file is not a standard bash feature (I think it is an Ubuntu thing), the standard way is to add alias definitions to your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: if you added your alias to ```~/.bash_aliases ```  or ```~/.bashrc``` don't forget to activate it by ```source ~/.bash_aliases ``` or ```source ~/.bashrc ```

Comment: The changes suggested above didn't work right away until I had restarted the terminal.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to not load the alias every time, to permanently store a alias command, do this.

Go to your home directory and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to view hidden files, one of these files would be `.bashrc`. Open it.

Now write the following command anywhere in the mainspace:

```
alias custom_command='original_command'
```

Your shortcut command will be stored permanently.

Comment: Apologies if this is a dumb question, but what is meant by "mainspace"? Where, if anywhere, would be the "safest" location for a beginner to insert this text?

Comment: Safest "Mainspace" would be the ones not indented and are not inside any scope (methods, brackets, etc.).

Comment: you need `source .bashrc` after closing `.bashrc` with ctrl-x and saying yes to save changes

Answer (score 7):

Aliases can take parameters. For example:

```
$ alias 777='sudo chmod -R 777 '
$ 777 MyFolder
```

will perform chmod recursively on `MyFolder`

Comment: Do you know how I can use alias for a command like this to trim a video?
 
`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -i input.mp4 -to 00:00:15 -c copy output.mp4` 

So that I can just type in the values that change, like the time and the filenames

Answer (score 3):

Generally the answer is to alias your command, as mentioned by M.Tarun. For your example with ssh you might want to add it to your `.ssh/config`:

```
Host someName
     HostName 123.45.7.123
     User user
```

Then call ssh with the name:

```
$ ssh someName
```

Your shell probably also has tab-completion for ssh. So you can just type `ssh s` and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

This also has the advantage that it works with other commands like `scp`:

```
$ scp some-file someName:a/path/
```

Whereas the alias approach would not work with this.